# Como passar valor do editText para atributo to tipo int no Android?

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma duvida em relação ao armazenamento de valor vindo do `EditText` para atributos do tipo `int` de uma classe. Para os atributos do tipo `String` faço assim:

```
objEquipamento.setMarcaModelo(edtMarcaModelo.getText().toString());
```

Mas e quando o meu atributo é do tipo `int`? e quero passar um número?
tenho que converter o valor ou exite algum método para `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Integer.html#parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-):

```
objEquipamento.setMarcaModelo(Integer.ParseInt(edtMarcaModelo.getText().toString().trim()));
```

Se `Integer.html#parseInt` não conseguir realizar a conversão, uma exceção [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) é lançada, se você preferir retornar um valor padrão em vez disso, faça:

```
public static int MyParseInt(String texto, int valorPadrao) {
   try {
      return Integer.parseInt(texto);
   } 
   catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return valorPadrao;
   }
}
```

Use assim:

```
objEquipamento.setMarcaModelo(MyParseInt(edtMarcaModelo.getText().toString().trim(), 0));
```

Para `double`, use [`Double.html#parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @Vinicius Existe sim, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Comment: para atributos do tipo double eu faço assim?
objServico.setValorTotal(Double.parseDouble(edtMarcaModelo.getText().toString()));

Answer (score 2):

Você terá que usar o método [Integer.ParseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) da seguinte forma:

```
try{
    objEquipamento.setMarcaModelo(Integer.ParseInt(edtMarcaModelo.getText().toString()));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      //erro ao converter
}
```

É importante você colocar o tratamento e obrigar o usuário a digitar de fato um Integer da seguinte forma no xml:

```
<EditText android:numeric="integer" ..../>
```

Comment: muito boa essa dica no xml, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o parseInt sim, porém como se trata de um editText, pode ser inserido um caractere não numérico, ocasionando uma exceção, logo, isto precisa ser tratado